# Inject angular directive and service. [$injector:unpr] error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am trying to inject a service in Angular js, but it gives following error.
Service name is $upload.
Code in my script located in the head of the page - `angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

Code in my controller `$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var file = $files[i];
      $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
        url: 'server/upload/url', 
        data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
        file: file, // or list of files: $files for html5 only
      }).progress(function(evt) {
        console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
      });
      //.error(...)
    }
  };`

Error displayed is : Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24uploadProvider%20%3C-%20%24upload

Comment: Show your controller declaration

Comment: Hi Chandermani, Here is my controll declaration function myCtrl ($scope, $http, $sce, $compile, $window, $upload) {

Comment: how is `$upload` service defined? have you loaded the service script properly?

Comment: One reason this can happen when you redefine your module `angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload'])` more than one once in your code

Comment: Did you include the service script in the base html page?

Comment: Yes Vishal, I have included the script in base HTML Page.